# How to create a program that continually accepts input from the user and evaluate all the input

Tags: python, loops, validation, while-loop, user-input

How can I create a program that continually accepts input from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
num = 0

while((a := input()) != "-0"):
    if (len(a) >= 2) and (a[0] in "/*-+"):
        num = eval(f"{num}{a}")
    else:
        print("Invalid input, try again.")
        
print(num)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! your codes work but how can I make the first input to only be with "+" or "-"? Like the first input of the user is "-9" or "+9" then in the next input they now can use the other operators.